# How to find make one table of proportions of demographic variables in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am having trouble with a simple command. How do I find the proportion of demographic variables (for example, proportion of English speakers in my population, or proportion of White respondents)?

I'd like to create a large table with all of the proportions, and would hopefull include mean age and median education level, but am having trouble finding the command. This is what I've tried:

```
table2 <- table(VR_Data$English)
prop.table(table2) 

table3 <- table(VR_Data$race)
prop.table(table3)

table4 <- table(VR_Data$male)
prop.table(table4)
```

If it helps, this is my data:

```
structure(list(study = c(4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1), TREATMENT = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TREATMENT4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TREATMENT2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TREATMENT3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), order = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), id = c(279, 
238, 239, 135, 143, 138), treatment = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), treatment_condition = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), control_condition = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), m_check1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), relationship = c(NA, NA, NA, 7, 6, 5), payment = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 10, 3, 3), educ_level = c(14, 14, 12, 16, 16, 18), golf = c(3, 
5, 3, 3, 2, 3), male = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), Asian = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Black = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Latino = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), White = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), age = c(27, 53, 49, 25, 28, 
24), English = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), education = c(16, 16, 14, 
14, 14, 16), enjoy = c(4, 1, 3.5, 4.25, 3.25, 3.5), RELATIONSHIP = c(4.33333349227905, 
1, 4.33333349227905, 3.66666674613953, 3.5, 3.66666674613953), 
    anxiety = c(3, 3.40000009536743, 2.20000004768372, 1.25, 
    2, 1.25), BEH_SIM = c(3, 1, 3.75, 2.75, 2.5, 1.75), sptconf = c(3.33333325386047, 
    1.5, 4, 4.83333349227905, 4, 3.66666674613953), NEG_EFFICACY = c(4, 
    1.16666662693024, 3.66666674613953, 4.83333349227905, 4.16666650772095, 
    4.5), spteffort = c(3.16666674613953, 3.5, 4.16666650772095, 
    3.16666674613953, 3.16666674613953, 3.5), SPTEFFORT_OTHER = c(3.16666674613953, 
    3.5, 3.5, 3.16666674613953, 3, 3.33333325386047), SIM_VALUES = c(3.75, 
    1, 3.75, 3.75, 1.5, 2.25), COOP_MOTIV = c(2.33333325386047, 
    3, 2.66666674613953, 5, 2.5, 2.66666674613953), COMP_MOTIV = c(5, 
    5, 3.20000004768372, 4.40000009536743, 2.40000009536743, 
    4.40000009536743), presence = c(NA, NA, NA, 2.79999995231628, 
    1.79999995231628, 2.59999990463257), environ = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, 3, 4, 3), openresponse = c(NA, NA, NA, 94.25, 86, 60), 
    TotalOwnerCommission = c(300, 266.666656494141, 258.333343505859, 
    266.666656494141, 383.333343505859, 325), TotalRangerComm = c(258.333343505859, 
    233.33332824707, 291.666656494141, 258.333343505859, 175, 
    166.66667175293), TotalComm = c(279.166687011719, 250, 275, 
    262.5, 279.166687011719, 245.833343505859), merge = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0), Control = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA), treatment_Shoes = c(0, 
    0, 0, NA, NA, NA), treatment_Instructions_Only = c(0, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, NA), treatment_Info_Only = c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA), treatment_Info_Instructions = c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA), 
    group = c("OwnerOnly", "OwnerOnly", "OwnerOnly", "", "", 
    ""), race = c(4, 2, 5, NA, NA, NA), race_a = c("", "", "", 
    "", "", ""), RELATIONSHIP_2 = c(9.02055358886719, 1, 9.02055358886719, 
    7.02113246917725, 6.54790019989014, 7.02113246917725), TotalOwnerCommission_2 = c(5196.15234375, 
    4354.64794921875, 4152.12744140625, 4354.64794921875, 7505.24560546875, 
    5859.02099609375)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I put all of these proportions into one table, with mean and medians? Is this possible? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should help you.

```
library(dplyr)

VR_Data %>% 
  summarize(English_prop = sum(English) / n(),
            White_prop = sum(White) / n(),
            male_prop = sum(male) / n(),
            age_avg = mean(age),
            education_avg = mean(education))
```

Should give you this...

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  English_prop White_prop male_prop age_avg education_avg
         <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>
1            1      0.667       0.5    34.3            15
```

Comment: Thanks so much,  but that code gives me this error: ```Error in summarize(., English_prop = sum(English)/n(), White_prop = sum(White)/n(), : argument "by" is missing, with no default```

Comment: @PhilJameson Try replacing 'summarize' with 'summarise'.

Comment: Oh great! That worked. But I get NA's for all the values? So sorry, thank you for all your help.

Comment: @PhilJameson. If your data contain some `NA` values, then modify bellmaneqn's code by including `na.rm=TRUE` in all of the summary functions. For example, `sum(English,  na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks Edward. That works. :) I always have trouble knowing when I can and cannot use na.rm =TRUE.